# Asymptotic convergence of the total length of a graph

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, algorithms, connectedness

I encoded the following algorithm: suppose we're in (0,1)x(0,1) and I randomly create a "village" one at a time. At each step, I link a newly randomly created village to the closest village already created.

So basically:
step 1: 1 village somewhere in (0,1)x(0,1)
step 2: I link village 2 to village 1
step 3: i create village 3 and link it to the closest village already existing (1 or 2)
etc...

Empirically I found that the total distance that link the villages all together grows like sqrt(n) when n goes to infinity.
Could anyone explain me why? I've though about it but could not come up with a good proof (I tried to find a recursive relationship but I did not get what I wanted). Also, when thinking about it, I realized there could be some issues when considering villages very close to the sides of the rectangle and so, you may not take this case into consideration.

Comment: Upvoted back to 0 as there's no good reason to downvote this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The density of villages goes up as $O(n)$, so the distance to the nearest one must go down as $O(1/\sqrt{n})$.  (Imagine a perfectly regular grid. If there are $n^2$ villages in the grid, the grid would be a square $n$ villages on a side, so their separation would be about $1/n$.)  The total distance would therefore be (with a slight abuse of notation) $\sum_{k=1}^n O(1/\sqrt{n}) \sim O(\sqrt{n})$.

ETA: The sum of $O(n^p)$ for $n$ from $1 \to \infty$ is $O(n^{p+1})$, broadly speaking.